# Найти и передать атрибут Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, input, attr

Есть HTML разметка:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
<img src="" class="panel-image" alt="image">
```

Задача:

При выборе файла для input нужно получить его value и присвоить это значение тегу img в атрибут src.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задумка в том, чтобы показать пользователю картинку, это можно реализовать так:

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-image');
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

for( let i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
  input[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    let val = URL.createObjectURL( this.files[0] );
    img[i].src = val;
    img[i].style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.panel-image {
  display: none;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
<img  class="panel-image" src="" alt="image">

<br><br><br>

<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
<img class="panel-image" src="" alt="image">
```

Comment: Именно это и требовалось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Получаем имя файла и записываем в **src** тега **img**:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e){
  var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
  $('.panel-image').attr('src', fileName);
});
```

Comment: Можно ли получить полный адрес? то-есть если я загружаю файл с компьютера нужно получить полный путь. К примеру: D:\face.jpg И передать его в атрибут src тега img